# Cookies acceptance policy and localStorage and sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm modifying our site cookies policy to be compliant and I get various contradictional information.
I also look other big sites and portals, but the question remains:

**Does cookie handling also includes handling of storage?** Or I can store whatever I please in storage and I don't have to ask for permission?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming we are talking about GDPR and similar acts (which are all enacted into individual member state laws under different names) "Cookie Handling" isn't actually what is covered by the law. It is "data collection and processing".

That means it makes absolutely no difference *where* you store the data, be it cookies, local storage, session storage, server storage, print outs - it's all covered by the General Data Protection Regulation in the EU (and similar laws in many other territories).

Solutions that only take care of cookies do not comply with the requirements.

There is an ePrivacy directive in draft that will provide additional clarity.

All of the EU legislation is actually quite readable (as legislation goes) and available on the [Europa website](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/data-protection-eu_en).